# How WAB apps knows the size of the screen to behave in mobile mode?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

All the apps generated via ArcGIS Web AppBuilder (2.21), hosted on IIS or on our ArcGIS Portal, begun to behave as we were accessing them from mobile devices (when we are using desktop pcs): popup windows initially closed, spaced widgets, etc. I'm not sure if it is happening since our version upgrade (from 10.8.1 to 10.9.1). I found a [topic](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-web-appbuilder-questions/adding-mobile-breakpoint-programmatically/td-p/130638) in a ESRI forum where is a solution (or workaround) using [URL parameters](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/latest/manage-apps/app-url-parameters.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_01F86DEC2181416888D44A32D3096887) (which I applied in one of our apps and it worked, using '?mobileBreakPoint=500') or [coding](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-web-appbuilder-questions/adding-mobile-breakpoint-programmatically/td-p/130638). But it does not answer why our apps begun to behave like that or where we could implement the code to affect all apps. So, where WAB's apps check screens size?